# Storing system data into graphite/statsd

Tags: statistics, graphite

I have setup `graphite` and `statsd` on a specific machine that will be dedicated for stats. Now, if I would like to connect my application servers to provide stats - what would be the best way?

I know that carbon does this for the stats machine already, but what do I do on the appservers that doesn't have graphite installed?

What I am looking for is to store `load`, `disk usage` and `memory free/used`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running collectd (http://collectd.org/) with a graphite agent (https://github.com/indygreg/collectd-carbon) would be an excellent start to gather the information you're after.

There is an almost unlimited amount of ways to get your data into graphite.

You can find a list of tools that have known to work very well with graphite on the readthedocs.org page: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.10/tools.html

Comment: Thank you! That made a lot of sense